# Serverless deploy to another AWS account than one authenticated with

Tags: serverless

My organisation has a centralised AWS account to perform actions from with roles that have access to perform actions on other accounts which trust the role.

However `serverless deploy` tries to deploy using the authenticated account. There doesn't seem to be a way to deploy the application to another account that the assumed role has access to.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify credentials using environment variables when running the commands, so they can indicate different accounts to act as.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html for the list, but using AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY definitely work for me